# Trouble proving operator norm satisfies $||A||_{\text {op}} = \inf \{c \in \mathbb R : ||Ax|| \le c||x|| \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am having trouble proving that the operator norm on $\text {Mat}_{n,n}(\mathbb R)$ given by $||A||_{\text {op}}=\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||$ satisfies $||A||_{\text {op}} = \inf \{c \in \mathbb R : ||Ax|| \le c||x|| \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n\}$.

I've already proved that $||A||_{\text {op}}$ is a norm.

I've considered whether $||Ax|| \le c||x|| \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n \Rightarrow c \ge\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||$, but haven't come to a conclusion.

Also, I'd like to show that $||A||_{\text {op}} \le ||A||_{\text {op}}||B||_{\text {op}}$.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch:**

$$\inf \{c \in \mathbb R : \lVert Ax\rVert \le c\lVert x\rVert \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n\}=\sup \{c \in \mathbb R : \frac{\lVert Ax\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}  \le c  \ \forall x\neq 0 \in \mathbb R^n\}=$$
Observe then: $\,\dfrac{\lVert Ax\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}=\dfrac{\lVert A(\lambda x)\rVert}{\lVert\lambda  x\rVert}$ for all $\lambda\neq 0$, so we can suppose as well $\lVert x\rVert=1$.

For  the multiplicative inequality, two cases:

- If $ Bx\neq 0$,write $\, \dfrac{\lVert ABx\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}= \dfrac{\lVert A(Bx)\rVert}{\lVert Bx\rVert}\cdot\dfrac{\lVert Bx\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}\leq \lVert A\rVert\cdot  \lVert B\rVert $ and take the supremum over all $x$ such that $Bx\neq 0$.
- If $Bx=0$, $\,\dfrac{\lVert ABx\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}=0\,$ anyway, and $0\leq \lVert A\rVert\cdot  \lVert B\rVert $ (!).

Comment: Why do you change $\inf$ to $\sup$ ?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\lVert A(Bx)\rVert}{\lVert Bx\rVert}\cdot\dfrac{\lVert Bx\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}\leq \lVert A\rVert\cdot  \lVert B\rVert $$ and why is this true ?

Comment: The relevant inequality is true for each factor, because the operator norm, say for B,  is also the supremum of $\frac{\lVert Bx\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}$ for all $x\neq 0$, as I observe at the beginning of the answer. For the $A(Bx)$ part, set $y=Bx$.

Comment: Why do you change $\inf$ to $\sup$ in the first line of the answer ?

Comment: Remember the sup of a set of numbers is the *smallest* of the upper bounds of the  elements of the set, and $c$ is an upper bound of $\Bigl\{\frac{\lVert Ax\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert},\ x\neq 0\Bigl\} $.